# Consequences of the positivity condition $v^t A v > 0$ for the eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ *symmetric* real matrix with n distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1 , ... , \lambda_n$.

a) Suppose $v^t(Av)$>0 for all v in $R^n$, v$\ne$0.  Show that all $\lambda_i$ are positive numbers.

b) Suppose $v^t(Av)>0$ for all $v=(v_1, ..., v_n) \in R^n$ with $v \ne 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i = 0$.  Show that at most one of the $\lambda_i$ is not a positive real number.

Edit: I have solved part (a), and am studying part (b).  There is a solution that uses the min-max theorem.  If you can offer an alternate solution to part (b) without using this theorem, I would love to see it. :-)

Thanks.

Comment: Note $v^t v$ is the length$^2$ of $v$, which is strictly positive if $v\neq 0$.

Comment: hmm...would it make any sense to multiply both sides of the inequality by v, in order to make use of  your hint?  otherwise, i don't see how i can get $v^tv$ ... since matrix multiplication is not commutative (so I can't push the v over one slot to the left.)

Comment: Try to put $A v= \lambda v$ into that inequality.

Comment: That's so cool :-), @JohnMa.  How about a hint for part(b)?  :-)

Comment: btw, for part(a), I came up with a hand-wavy answer:  A being symmetric has the same eigendecomposition and singular value decomposition (just look at the eigenvalues of $A^tA$.)  Also, A symmetric has full rank, which means every singular value must be positive.  Hence, every eigenvalue of A must be positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** (For (b).) Suppose that there are (at least) two nonpositive eigenvalues, and let $\Bbb W$ denote the span of their eigenspaces. What can we say about $v^T A v$ for $v \in \Bbb W$?

> **Additional hint** The set $\{v : v_1 + \cdots + v_n = 0\}$ is the kernel of a linear functional and hence is a subspace. What is its dimension? What can we say about the dimension of its intersection with $\Bbb W$?

Comment: Hi @Travis, I was pretty close :-( I wanted to stick with your first hint, but was stuck for awhile with addition of 4 terms of inner products (or norm-squared of vectors) and didn't know what to do with them.  Then I took a peak at a student solution and it pretty much gave it away, unfortunately.  The inner products between vectors from the different eigenspaces are zero, of course, because of the orthogonality of the eigenvectors - guaranteed by the Spectral Theorem and by A being symmetric.  Then I am left with two terms: $\lambda_1||v_1||^2 + \lambda_2||v_2||^2$ >0.

Comment: Then I gave 4 cases of how $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ could both be non-positive - each case contradicts the positivity assumption, and we are done.

Comment: Actually, two things:  I didn't actually use the fact that the entries of v sum to zero.  That might indicate that my work could be wrong somewhere - it's pretty rare to get more assumptions than necessary.  So, I'll double-check my work.

Comment: Second thing is:  I only supposed, for contradiction, that there were *two* non-positive eigenvalues.  Do you think I have to generalize the proof to account for 3 or more non-positive eigenvalues?

Comment: The generalization of the proof would probably just involve a lot more inner products summing to zero, and then addition of several more terms, leading to many more cases to consider to show the contradiction of the positivity assumption. So, this is probably not the ideal way to go...

Comment: @LebronJames I don't quite follow your solution, but it's anyway not the one I had in mind. By assumption, for all nonzero $v \in \Bbb V := \{v : v_1 + \cdots + v_n = 0\}$ we have $v^T A v > 0$. On the other hand, all $v \in \Bbb W$ can be written as a sum of vectors with nonpositive eigenvalues, so for such $v$ we have $v^T A v \leq 0$. So, we must have $\Bbb V \cap \Bbb W = \{0\}$. Then, we can use the dimensions of $\Bbb V$ and $\Bbb W$ to derive a contradiction (here is where you use the definition of $\Bbb V$).

Comment: Ah, ok got it.  Can I ask one more question re: this problem?  Is the inner product "distributive", in the sense that (a+b)*(c+d) = a*c + a*d + b*c + b*d, where * is the inner product operation, and a,b,c,d are vectors.

Comment: ...according to my search on MSE, it *is* distributive. :-)  Thanks again, @travis.  Have a great night.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful, cheers.